# How to remove the hash from Compass's generated sprite image filenames?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Compass uses chunky_png to render the sprites. It adds a hash to the end of the file to force caches to download the new image sprites. Is there a way to turn this cache busting off?

Comment: The sprite hash isn't for browser cache busting (though it has that effect) but so Compass can identify the generated file.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Unfortunately `asset_cache_buster :none` option does not disable adding the hash to the end of the filename.

Like I wrote few time ago (in french), Compass has no way to disable the cache hash buster, but I propose [a solution](http://pioupioum.fr/developpement/compass-sprites-supprimer-cache-buster.html).
In your configuration file (eg `config.rb`) add the following lines:

```ruby
# Make a copy of sprites with a name that has no uniqueness of the hash.
on_sprite_saved do |filename|
  if File.exists?(filename)
    FileUtils.cp filename, filename.gsub(%r{-s[a-z0-9]{10}\.png$}, '.png')
  end
end

# Replace in stylesheets generated references to sprites
# by their counterparts without the hash uniqueness.
on_stylesheet_saved do |filename|
  if File.exists?(filename)
    css = File.read filename
    File.open(filename, 'w+') do |f|
      f << css.gsub(%r{-s[a-z0-9]{10}\.png}, '.png')
    end
  end
end
```

Now, uses `compass clean`to remove generated files and restarts a compilation with `compass compile`.
You obtain, for example, a `images/icons-scb1e5456d5.png` file **and** a `images/icons.png` file. In the stylesheets, all references to the sprites now point to the version without hash.

Be sure to keep the file has a hash provided to optimize compile times by Compass.

Comment: Thanks for this, I personally chose to use FileUtils.mv instead of FileUtils.cp so that the hold file doesnt hang around

Comment: Using this with grunt-contrib-sass doesn't seem to trigger the on_stylesheet_saved block, leaving the css background properties referencing the file with the hash in it rather than unhashed one. Using it with grunt-contrib-compass did trigger it though.

Comment: @yuvilio this hook is providing by Compass and doesn't exists in Sass. Thx for the reminder!

Comment: What's the purpose of this? IME the sprite hash changes only when the generated image changes, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure why `asset_cache_buster :none` didn't work for you, but it sure did for me.

Answer (score 22):

Set `asset_cache_buster :none` in your config.rb as [documented in their configuration reference](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/)

Comment: This solution does not prevent Compass from putting hash as postfix to sprite file name what is a problem in given question.

Answer (score 4):

Better solution can be found in another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16478392/277937).

It's better because:

1. Script changes name before generating sprite - not after.
2. Because of point 1. there is no need to hardly change `.css` auto generated file. It's generated with correct name from beginning.
3. Accepted solution makes `cp` (copy) of generated sprite with hash and it stays in file system / repo as duplicate which is quite bad. Additionally it's still seen as changed with local repo so you commit two identical files. Solution could do `mv` to change generated hash file name to clear one, but in this case sprite would be generated every time you use it in `.scss` file so it's even worse.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested with sprites, but this works with `replace-text-with-dimensions`, for example:

config.rb:

```
# disable asset cache buster
asset_cache_buster do |http_path, real_path|
  nil
end
```

Found at [The compass configuration file at caring.com](https://gist.github.com/784033)