# Compass Sprite Filename

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am trying to control compass sprite filenames.

My deployment scripts require that images be included in the project file (.Net).
Since compass creates new files each time it renders the sprite (to break caching, I presume)., I have to explicitly get rid of the old reference and add the new.

Has anyone had experience with this?

I don't really want to use an `after_build` script, but if that's what I have to do I'll take all the suggestions you've got.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume to break the caching, you can look at my answer to the question [How to turn off COMPASS SASS cache busting?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9332472/392725), which automatically created a copy of sprites without hashing.