# Remove the random string appended to sprite filename with Compass/Sass

Tags: css, ruby, sass, sprite, compass-sass

I've recently been using Compass with Sass to do some CSS spriting, as it's extremely useful.

However, the filename is always appended with a random string. E.g. **icons-s5eb424578c.png**. And I don't want this random string to be appended, because it means I'm required to upload both the new CSS file & the new sprite image every time there's a change.

So, does anyone know which Ruby or other config file within the Compass gem directory, that is appending this random string? Then I can just comment the code out for that bit. Unless I'm missing an official variable I can set within Compass to tell it I don't want this string appended?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: See if this helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183133/how-to-turn-off-compass-sass-cache-busting

Comment: Thank you @cimmanon. That was just the answer I was looking for. If I'd known it was a caching issue my search queries may have got me there!

Comment: It's not random, it's [a hash identifying the generated file](https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1374). It shouldn't be changing on every compile, only when the sprites change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your project config file enter something like this

```
asset_cache_buster :none

# Make a copy of sprites with a name that has no uniqueness of the hash.
on_sprite_saved do |filename|
  if File.exists?(filename)
    FileUtils.mv filename, filename.gsub(%r{-s[a-z0-9]{10}\.png$}, '.png')
  end
end

# Replace in stylesheets generated references to sprites
# by their counterparts without the hash uniqueness.
on_stylesheet_saved do |filename|
  if File.exists?(filename)
    css = File.read filename
    File.open(filename, 'w+') do |f|
      f << css.gsub(%r{-s([a-z0-9]{10})\.png}, '.png?v\1')
    end
  end
end
```

credits goes here [How to remove the hash from Compass's generated sprite image filenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183133/how-to-turn-off-compass-sass-cache-busting#9332472)

Answer (score 17):

Try to add these lines into your `config.rb`:

```
module Compass::SassExtensions::Functions::Sprites
  def sprite_url(map)
    verify_map(map, "sprite-url")
    map.generate
    generated_image_url(Sass::Script::String.new(map.name_and_hash))
  end
end

module Compass::SassExtensions::Sprites::SpriteMethods
  def name_and_hash
    "sprite-#{path}.png"
  end

  def cleanup_old_sprites
    Dir[File.join(::Compass.configuration.generated_images_path, "sprite-#{path}.png")].each do |file|
      log :remove, file
      FileUtils.rm file
      ::Compass.configuration.run_sprite_removed(file)
    end
  end
end

module Compass
  class << SpriteImporter
    def find_all_sprite_map_files(path)
      glob = "sprite-*{#{self::VALID_EXTENSIONS.join(",")}}"
      Dir.glob(File.join(path, "**", glob))
    end
  end
end
```

Works for me with `Compass 0.12.2 (Alnilam)`

Comment: This solution is so much better than first one. It changes names before generating, not after with changing css directly.