# How to change default sprite name generated by compass?

Tags: ruby, sass, compass

I have a problem with compass sprites.

I used two different config.rb files for it, but I need to generate sprites in same directory.

But this sprites deleted each other.

Now sprites filename is icons-s2e073c2bbc.png

How can I change default file name for one of them to sprites-s2e073c2bbc.png (or something like this)

Comment: Compass version - 1.1.0.alpha.3 (Polaris).

Comment: I tried this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/16478392/4357197 . But I have an error NameError on line ["234"] of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.1.0.alpha.3/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb: uninitialized constant Compass::Configuration::Serialization::Compass::Core

Answer (score 0):

It's not a best solution, but maybe it will be help someone

I added this code in config.rb file and now it save sprite file in another directory and there is no conflict with another sprite files.

```
generated_images_dir = 'images/travel_sprite'
http_generated_images_dir = "/images/travel_sprite"
http_generated_images_path = "/images/travel_sprite"
```