# Turn off hash sprite naming for specified file in SASS / Compass

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to make some sprite for Google maps I need to turn off that hash tag `maps-s6f45423a37.png` to `maps.png` I've grabbed this code below and tried to make do loop, but since I don't know ruby it doesn't work :)

```
on_sprite_saved do |filename|
test=filename.gsub(%r{-s[a-z0-9]{10}\.png$}, '.png')
  if test=='maps.png'
    FileUtils.cp filename, filename.gsub(%r{-s[a-z0-9]{10}\.png$}, '.png')
  end
end
```

how to do it thanks :)

Comment: Why are you using `%r` and not `/`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn off COMPASS SASS cache busting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183133/how-to-turn-off-compass-sass-cache-busting)

Comment: It is not duplicate I've grabbed that code from [How to turn off COMPASS SASS cache busting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183133/how-to-turn-off-compass-sass-cache-busting) and I'm trying to make condition just for one file and maybe delete file with hash name. @Linuxios i really don't know ruby this is my "first" line of code. I just need that condition for one file and maybe deletion!